# How to fix the error "JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory"?

Tags: cordova, jvm

I use cordova in my app.

I ran the command

```
сordova platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^8.0.0
Platform android already added.
```

then cordova build and saw the following error

```
hacking Java JDK and AndroidSDKversions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk (DEPRECATED)

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

the readlink-f $(which java) command shows

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

I'm confused and upset, how to solve this problem?

---

I change my .bashrc and add strings

```
setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/
setenv PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

if I run echo $JAVA_HOME now I seen

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I run cordova build I see

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk (DEPRECATED)
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Unable to start the daemon process.
```

whats wrong?

Comment: Make sure you open a new terminal window after changes

Answer (score 2):

This seems environment variable is not set for java_home,Try this from your command prompt shell by running it as admin, Though you do not need to restart the machine however you can if you want.

```
setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/
setenv PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. But this is not solution my problem. I change my question now...

Comment: ok so this seems now Java_Home error is not there.

by looking at your updated questions, i see this is certainly a problem with gradle version conflict. Please review the version requirement and fix it with installing the correct one.
Last time i had this problem was when i was migrating my old gradle project to the new one.

Comment: @Rahil Mishra
I'm still in the middle of a problem. I am very upset that I am facing so many difficulties when developing on cordova. 
It's killing my time and energy.

after run gradle --stacktrace

I see it https://pastebin.com/csktqsLv